# Delete older log files based on max history using logback

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback

I need to delete old log files based on max history using logback. My log file format is app.log. 
Also i need to use fixedwindowrolling policy to rotate the log files based on size. Rotation file format is app.log.1 , app.log.2 ......app.log.n .

How do i delete these non rotated and rotated files old log files . ? 
Rotated file name pattern     : app.log.1 ..app.log.n
Non rotated file name pattern : app.log

Comment: Did you look at the [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender)?

Comment: Yes.I am using rollingFileAppender only.Is it possible to rotate files and delete old files in a single rolling file appender